# Spring Boot Stripe Payment Integration

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-boot, stripe-payments, checkout

I am developing a web application where a user can buy a course for learning. For payment, I am trying to implement Stripe payment gateway. I am a beginner in implementation of payment gateway.
I am unaware and bit confused that where should I start from. I have custom payment form where I am taking cardholder name, card number, CVV, card expiration date and a static amount to buy that course. I want to persist credit card data like card number, expiry date and customer ID into my database (MySql). I have public and secret key (test-mode). I have configured both keys in my **application.yml** file.

Below is my controller where I have written checkout function:

```
@RequestMapping(value= {WebUrl.checkout},method= {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
    public ModelAndView checkout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = null;
        User loginuser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
        if(loginuser == null) {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView("redirect:.."+WebUrl.studentlogin);
        }else {
            modelAndView = new ModelAndView(WebUrl.checkout);
            modelAndView.addObject("loginuser", loginuser);
            modelAndView.addObject("amount", 1);
            modelAndView.addObject("stripePublicKey", stripePublicKey);
            modelAndView.addObject("currency", ChargeRequest.Currency.USD);
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Below is my StripePayment service class:

```
public Charge createCharge(String userid, String token, int amount, String cardnumber, String cardexpirydate) {
    Charge chargeObj = null;
        try {
            Long uid = Long.parseLong(userid);
            User userById = userDao.findByUserid(uid);
            if(userById != null) {
                String email = userById.getEmail();
                Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
                chargeParams.put("description","Charge for "+email);
                chargeParams.put("currency",chargeRequest.getCurrency());
                chargeParams.put("amount", amount);
                chargeParams.put("source",chargeRequest.getStripeToken());
                
                chargeObj = Charge.create(chargeParams);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return chargeObj;
    }
}
```

Below is my API for payment:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ApiUrl.createCharge, method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET }, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> createCharge(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, @PathVariable("token") String token, @PathVariable("cardExpiryDate") String cardexpiry, @PathVariable("userid") String userid, @PathVariable("cardNumber") String cardnumber) {
        CustomResponse = ResponseFactory.getResponse(request);
        try {
            if(token == null || token == "") {
                CustomResponse.setResponse("Stripe payment token is missing. please try again later.");
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
                CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
            }
            Charge charge = stripeService.createCharge(userid, token, 100, cardnumber, cardexpiry);//1 usd or 100 cents
            Long uid = Long.parseLong(userid);
            User user = userDao.findByUserid(uid);
            UserPayment paymentByUser = new UserPayment();
            if(cardexpiry != null || cardexpiry != "") {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                Date date = sdf.parse(cardexpiry);
                paymentByUser.setCardExpiryDate(date);
            }
            paymentByUser.setCardNumber(cardnumber);
            paymentByUser.setUserid(user);
            paymentByUser.setAmount(chargeamount.doubleValue());
            UserPayment payment = userPaymentDao.save(paymentByUser);
            if (charge != null && payment != null) {
                CustomResponse.setResponse("Success your charge id is "+charge);
                CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.OK);
                CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.OK_CODE);
                CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.SuccessMsg);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            CustomResponse.setResponse(null);
            CustomResponse.setStatus(CustomStatus.Error);
            CustomResponse.setStatusCode(CustomStatus.Error_CODE);
            CustomResponse.setResponseMessage(CustomStatus.ErrorMsg);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseDao>(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

**I am confused here whether I am missing something or not. Please suggest me.**What should be major steps to follow for Stripe payment gateway implementation?
[image]

Comment: You should absolutely not be persisting credit card data unless you have the required PCI compliance! Instead use Stripe.js and Elements to collect payment data in a compliant way.

Comment: @JonathanSteele But I want to keep a record of customers buying that course in my DB. So how should I do for this thing?

Comment: You could store the resulting Payment Intent in your database, which contains no credit card data. You should absolutely not be handling raw credit card data yourself.

Comment: @JonathanSteele Could you please share some example or some tutorial doc for Payment Intent?

Comment: This is a good starting guide: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Comment: @JonathanSteele In this doc, there mention that you have to choose at least one payment method and then create Payment Intent. But in my web app there is only one way of accepting payment and that is through credit card. Then also need to create Payment Intent?

Comment: Yep, so you'd pass `payment_method_types: ['card']` when creating your Payment Intent: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_types

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242916/discussion-between-rakhi-and-jonathan-steele).